# How to create a kubernetes container and run it from another pod

Tags: kubernetes, grpc-java

I have a grpc micro-service A running in kubernetes cluster. When this service is called, I would like to create an instance of another grpc micro-service B and run it in the same cluster. I have the image of the second service included in the container A. Now how can I create and run the micro-service B as another pod in the cluster.

Thanks
Madhu

Comment: Sorry I should have provided more details. Service B is grpc micro-service written using python. This is a watson service which needs to be trained on a set of data. The data will be sent from UI using a spreadsheet. The back end service which is service A should take this data and spin a container/pod for the service B with this data. The service B takes this data and creates a Cartesian product of this data (this data will be >200MB) and will respond to queries from user who pushed the data.  This process can be repeated by any other user. So for each users data we need to spin a pod.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an image inside, what you need is a kubernetes client that you will use to create deployment/job/pod. Your pod needs a serviceaccount that has RBAC role/clusterrole allowing for creation of what you need. This way you can create a service that on demand interacts with kubernetes api and creates what you want.

All in all, it's a very similar concept to how operators work, so looking at https://github.com/operator-framework might provide some usefull insights, but even just launching kubectl inside the pod might be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will review the information you provided and try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do exactly what you're asking, you can use a kubernetes client and spin up a pod, wait on its status, get its IP and talk to it and then kill it; however you should really rethink your design. There's a reason you don't want to handle your own resources - if pod A spins up pod B and midway through its work pod A looses connection to pod B, pod B becomes orphaned. It is possible to deal with this too but I'd rather avoid this altogether. Try to design your systems with more flexible coupling, maybe you can use a queue instead of grpc?

Answer (score 0):

I found this good open source project for kubenetes API java-client  https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client with examples of how to do this.

I added this example in response to the good suggestion made below.

It has examples for creating Pods, Deployments, CronJobs etc.

For creating a Deployment the example provided is:
    https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/DeploymentExamples.java

```
public class DeploymentExamples {
  private static final Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeploymentExamples.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Config config = new ConfigBuilder().build();
      KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);

      try {
       // Create a namespace for all our stuff
       Namespace ns = new NamespaceBuilder()
             .withNewMetadata()
             .withName("thisisatest")
             .addToLabels("this", "rocks")
             .endMetadata().build();
       log("Created namespace", client.namespaces().createOrReplace(ns));

        ServiceAccount fabric8 = new ServiceAccountBuilder()
            .withNewMetadata()
            .withName("fabric8")
            .endMetadata().build();
        client
            .serviceAccounts()
            .inNamespace("thisisatest")
            .createOrReplace(fabric8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           System.out.println("Iteration:" + (i+1));
           Deployment deployment = new DeploymentBuilder()
                .withNewMetadata()
                .withName("nginx")
                .endMetadata()
                .withNewSpec()
                .withReplicas(1)
                .withNewTemplate()
                .withNewMetadata()
                .addToLabels("app", "nginx")
                .endMetadata()
                .withNewSpec()
                .addNewContainer()
                .withName("nginx")
                .withImage("nginx")
                .addNewPort()
                .withContainerPort(80)
                .endPort()
                .endContainer()
                .endSpec()
                .endTemplate()
                .withNewSelector()
                .addToMatchLabels("app", "nginx")
                .endSelector()
                .endSpec()
                .build();

            deployment = client
                 .apps()
                 .deployments()
                 .inNamespace("thisisatest")
                 .create(deployment);
            log("Created deployment", deployment);

            System.out.println("Scaling up:" + 
                deployment.getMetadata().getName());
            client
               .apps()
               .deployments()
               .inNamespace("thisisatest")
               .withName("nginx").scale(2, true);
            log("Created replica sets:", client.apps().replicaSets()
               .inNamespace("thisisatest").list().getItems());
            System.out.println("Deleting:" + 
               deployment.getMetadata().getName());
            client.resource(deployment).delete();
       }
       log("Done.");
    }finally {
        client.namespaces().withName("thisisatest").delete();
        client.close();
    }
```

Madhu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes